# Include multiple conditionals from nested select query

Tags: postgresql

I have a function which returns `min_time` and `max_time` which I would like to use in a SELECT query as constraints for a timestamp column. Below is how I can think to do it but I would prefer to not have to run the query twice.

```
SELECT timestamp, col FROM data
    WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 
        (SELECT min_time FROM get_time_limits()) 
        AND 
        (SELECT max_time FROM get_time_limits());
```

Is there a way to use multiple columns from a single nested SELECT query as constraints in another query?

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE test(timestamp TIMESTAMPTZ, col INTEGER);

INSERT INTO test (
    SELECT generate_series(
        NOW() - INTERVAL '10 days', 
        NOW(), 
        INTERVAL '1 day'), 
        generate_series(1, 11)
    );
```

Example min/max time:

```
'2023-03-23 00:00:00+00'::TIMESTAMPTZ
'2023-03-29 00:00:00+00'::TIMESTAMPTZ
```

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977). Do you want the same query to work for _both_ SQL Server and Postgres? Why?

Comment: I just need it to work for postgres. The function `get_time_limits()` returns `min_time::TIMESTAMPTZ, max_time::TIMESTAMPTZ`. The table, `data`, has columns `timestamp::TIMESTAMPTZ, col INTEGER`.

Comment: I realized I mislabeled as sql-server. Tags updated to just postgres @mustaccio

Comment: Is `get_time_limits()` a STABLE [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)? (`{ IMMUTABLE | STABLE | VOLATILE }`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your function return a [tstzrange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-EXAMPLES) then you can use something like this:

```
SELECT timestamp, col 
FROM data
WHERE timestamp <@ get_time_limits()
```

I haven't tried, but the following should work using the current function:

```
SELECT timestamp, col 
FROM data
WHERE timestamp <@ (select tstzrange(min_time, max_time, '[]') from get_time_limits())
```

Comment: This looks like it would work for the simple query I explained above but the actual query I am doing uses TimescaleDB's `time_bucket_gapfill` which requires a more specific start/end in the WHERE clause. I will accept the answer for others but will need to do some more digging for my use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just do a join, using the function as a virtual table:

```
SELECT timestamp, col FROM data, get_time_limits()
    WHERE timestamp BETWEEN min_time AND max_time;
```